# Change color of Rectangles with clicks from another rectangle excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have 10 red rectangles and another blue one - UP - that should control their color. The rectangle number 1 is always green. If I click the UP rectangle, rectangle 2 should change color to green and if I click again on UP, rectangle 3 should change color to green and if I click 9 times, all the rectangles should be green. The code that I made goes only 1 step. Any help is welcomed. Thank you.

```
public i as long
Sub test()
Dim x As Long, y As Long
i = 2
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle " & i)).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 240, 0)
i = i + 1

   Debug.Print i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: So you actually start with one green, 9 red and 1 blue? What order are these shapes in? 1 green, 9 red and then the blue?

Comment: Also, avoid referencing by Shape number where possible as this can get out of sync quickly. Give the shapes names and refer to them in a loop. You could loop an array of containing the shape names.

Comment: I added a print screen

Comment: What you have is 9 blue, 2 green and 1 red. I am assuming the UP button should either be blue or Green but exempt from any change. I further assume Down is red and exempt from change. Therefore you have 10 shapes to consider of which 1 is always green and the other nine start red and then go green or start blue and then go green. You need to be clear on these before you can apply the correct changes. Also, how are these shapes numbered and is this numbering static i.e.  bottom most is always Rectangle 1 etc? I prefer working with named shapes to avoid any problems referencing by shape number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simply `For Loop` will do the job.

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 10
        On Error Resume Next
        Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle " & i)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not sh Is Nothing Then
            If sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB <> RGB(0, 240, 0) Then
                sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 240, 0)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub Test2()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim v As Variant

    For Each v In Array("Rectangle 2", "Rectangle 3", "Rectangle 4", "Rectangle 5", "Rectangle 6", "Rectangle 7", "Rectangle 8", "Rectangle 9", "Rectangle 10")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(v)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not sh Is Nothing Then
            If sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB <> RGB(0, 240, 0) Then
                sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 240, 0)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I think OP might need to consider the ordering of the shapes, the possibility that the numbers do not match so names would be better and there is the matter of the blue rectangle and its position (shape number).

Comment: The standard naming convention for a Shape is Shape Type + Space + Enumerator `Rectangle 1`, your code doesn't have the space.  Try changing `Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle" & i)` to `Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle " & i)`

Comment: I updated my answer using the correct naming convention.  I also added a sub routine that will allow you to iterate over an array of names as suggested by @QHarr.